# How can I solve java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm solving a challenge about making an algorithm.

> There is a game of land. 
>   The Land of Landing game consists of 4 rows in total N rows, with scores in all the columns. 
>   When stepping down from the first row, down one row, you must step down on one of the four squares of each row.
>   However, there is a special rule that can not be repeated in the same row when landing one row at a time.

For example,

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 |

| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |

| 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |

If you have stepped on line 1 through line 4 (5), you can not step on line 4 (8) on line 2.

I was trying to use Dynamic Programming in Java.

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.*;
class Solution {
   int [][] dp = new int[100001][4];

   int solution(int[][] land) {
    int r = land.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        dp[0][i] = land[0][i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <r; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < 4; ++k)
            {
                if (j != k)
                {
                    dp[i][j] = Math.max(dp[i][j], land[i][j] + dp[i-1][k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int ans = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        ans = Math.max(ans, dp[r-1][i]);
    }
    return ans;
   }
}
```

it shows error

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

I was thinking that it was probably something wrong with the Conditional statement.

In C++, these conditional statements are right. It's running perfect. Why am I getting an error in Java? Is there any difference using array between Java and C++?

Can you please tell me how can I solve this error?

Comment: Please don't use snippets for Java code. Snippets are **only** for JavaScript/html/css code.

Comment: If the same code worked 'fine' in C++, you were probably reading outside the allocated array, which is essentially a buffer overflow type bug.

Answer (score 1):

`dp[i-1][k]` - `i` starts from ZERO in upper loop, so results of this expression becomes -1 as index.

Java array index starts from ZERO, not -1, which is why `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I don't know the business case, but one way to solve this is, start first for loop from 1 instead 0.

Comment: Java arrays are zero based! Thats why

Comment: then should I change the '0' to '1' in all conditional statements?

Comment: If you see a condition which results index to -1, then those should be changed. There are no subtract operations on j & K, so it may never be -1.  But be-careful with my set index to 1 suggestion, because you may loose data if your source array has data at index 0. Your data and business requirement determines the exact solution. Good luck!